# low resolution displaying on monitor in raspbian

Tags: raspbian, video, display, composite-video

I have low video output quality on the raspberry pi.  I am using the analog output, on a 24" display which has an ideal resolution of 1920x1200. however I only get about 20" of that, at a of resolution 680x320. I have looked in the settings and fond nothing to increase the resolution.

Fine. So then I went looking for xorg.conf but that file doesn't exist here.

Before I get carried away trying to troubleshoot the video problems I am having the normal Linux way, what is the optimal raspberry pi way to improve, control, and troubleshoot display resolution?

Answer (score 3):

On the Pi you can set this in /boot/config.txt or on the boot partition on a Windows/Mac/Linux computer.

See instructions in

https://github.com/Evilpaul/RPi-config/blob/master/config.txt

Comment: How about a line number or something. Is that the extented version of /boot/config.txt ? Ill look there.